# How do I move my Zune software to a new machine?

Tags: windows-7, podcasts, zune, zune-software

I have Zune installed on a computer and want to move this to a new Windows 7 computer.

Although I haven't tried this yet I'm guessing that I could install the Zune software on Windows 7. However, how do I move all my subscriptions to podcasts etc. over to the Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there's no way to do a backup for Zune software...

Best thing is to write the names of all your podcasts and start adding them to your new Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large your Zune model is (4, 8, 30, etc), you could sync everything to your Zune:  playlists, podcasts, music, whatever else.  Then install the Zune software on your new machine, and then go to 'device'.  Then right-click on anything (except playlists, sorry) you want to transfer to the new machine/software and select "copy to my collection".  Voila, and you have it!  Just now saw this question, hope it helps!